# Ipad photos not rotated when uploaded to a website directly from iPad but ok when uploaded from the computer

Tags: php, ipad, orientation, exif

I'm developing a PHP website, and when I upload a photo taken from the ipad in portrait mode, it appears in landscape on the website, yet when I upload the very same photo from the computer (no changes made to the photo) it appears correctly in landscape mode. All landscape photos appear in landscape orientation just fine.

I've tried to find a way to fix this, and read about getting the orientation from the EXIF data, but the "orientation" tag is actually always the same (1 if I remember correctly) whether the photo has been taken in landscape or portrait.

I've tried to upload a portrait photo to flickr from the ipad and it appears correctly in portrait mode, so what am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php#110894
Credit: chadsmith729 at gmail dot com.

I haven't tested this solution myself..

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_FILES['image_upload']['tmp_name']));
$exif = exif_read_data($_FILES['image_upload']['tmp_name']);
if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    switch($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 8:
            $image = imagerotate($image,90,0);
            break;
        case 3:
            $image = imagerotate($image,180,0);
            break;
        case 6:
            $image = imagerotate($image,-90,0);
            break;
    }
}
// $image now contains a resource with the image oriented correctly
?>
```

This should work with all Apple products (iPod, iPhone and iPad)

Comment: Iffy giving an untested solution as an answer. That's basically saying you don't know if it works. Also, I hope Chad doesn't mind you posting his email publicly

Comment: Works like a charm. Had to switch 90 with -90 and vice versa though.