# JPEG image appearing differently in android and IOS backend php webservice

Tags: php, android, ios, image, google-chrome

I have run into a strange scenario . I am using php webservices (REST) for Android and IOS app. The problem is the jpeg image uploaded is showing differently in the apps.. Android shows it correctly while IOS shows it 90 rotated position. The same happens while the URL to the image is taken in different browsers. 90 degree rotated in chrome and in correct position mozilla and firefox.[image: URL to the image]

Whats the problem here..? pls help me with suggestions. This happens only for this particular image. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It probably is ios being helpful by respecting the orientation exif header in the jpeg. Make sure your image has this information stripped off and you should be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, you might want to check this:

[Iphone imagecopy rotates my image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217339/iphone-imagecopy-rotates-my-image)

IOS gives information with the picture, and most previewers will rotate the image automatically, so the only way you can fix that is rotate it again with [imagerotate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php)

Here's my piece of code:

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg(img.png);
$exif = exif_read_data(img.png);
if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    switch($exif['Orientation']) {
    case 8:
        $img = imagerotate($img,90,0);
        break;
    case 3:
        $img = imagerotate($img,180,0);
        break;
    case 6:
        $img = imagerotate($img,-90,0);
        break;
    }
}
```

I hope this can help you a bit

Comment: @Bananamoon But i have problem with only this image..so i cannot rotate it ..that will affect other images right?

Comment: Did you take the specific picture with ios?

Comment: yeah i took the specific picutre..Actually i am uploading the image from a compuer. not from any device..android and IOS..i am mentioning about your previous comment..

Comment: Say you took that image with your ios device, and send it to your computer, the image will still have the exif information on there. So uploading it from a computer will not change the rotation I'm afraid. I think you will have to look into Exif and try it out to see if the image really has the information in it